# TeamCity build number independent artifacts

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

My TeamCity's nightly build produces more than 130Mb java doc as Build Configuration artifact.
I have to share these artifact for other teams(developers), but javadoc every time has another one URL(I know that it's possible to get it like .lastFinished), and get's new place on Build Machine.
Is it possible on each build replace old artifact with new one because I don't need need previous versions? And have independent from build version URL for accessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure TeamCity to delete artifacts after the n-th subsequent build - set this to 1, and it won't keep much for you. Look under Administration at Build History Clean-up Policy.

And the independent from build version URL should then probably be the .lastFinished one you mention.